# how to convert image to base64 to send it using http post requests flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm trying to send a Base64 string to a server using [Requests](https://pub.dev/packages/requests) package. I'm getting the image file using [Flutter image Picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) package, here is a snip of my code:

**Getting the Image**

```dart
  File _image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _image = File(pickedFile.path);
    });
  }
```

**Converting and sending it**

```dart
    List<int> imageBytes = _image.readAsBytesSync();
    String  base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);

      var r = await Requests.post(
        'my_URL',
        headers: {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'},
        body: {
          'image':'$base64Image',
        }
      );
```

This send null to the server, any suggestion about how to do it in the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
List<int> imageBytes = _image.readAsBytesSync();
```

To

```
List<int> imageBytes = await _image.readAsBytesSync();
```

It could help.